# Express a parametric abbreviation in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I want to abreviate the equivalence class of a point:

```
r `` {p}
```

to

```
[p]
```

What is the right way to this in Isabelle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this in a context where `r` is fixed, e.g. an anonymous context or a locale:

```
context
  fixes r :: "('a × 'a) set"
begin

abbreviation foo ("⟨_⟩" 1000) where
  "⟨p⟩ ≡ r `` {p}"
```

I used chevrons instead of brackets here because brackets would clash with the syntax for lists, so it wou

Comment: Can I not use it locally? I mean the langle will also clash eventually with something...

Comment: No. Syntax is, unfortunately, always global. And there is no ‘shadowing’ either – if you introduce syntax that clashes with existing syntax, you will have ambiguous parse trees. If the ambiguity can be resolved by type class constraints, it still sort of works though. You could disable the existing syntax for lists and re-enable it later, but I would advise against that.

Comment: Also, I would advise against using too much custom syntax. Writing something like `cl p` (for ‘class’) is not much longer than your syntax. However, since your syntax only exists within this one context, it's probably not a problem if you do use it and it's unlikely to clash with anything even in the future.